# prxchange function

Tags: sas

I have a question on prxchange function.
I have a variable with alphanumeric characters, special characters and blanks, and I want to obtain the variable without numbers and special characters, but not remove spaces

I use: `UPCASE(prxchange(" s/[^A-Z]//i",-1,variable));`
but I obtain values without spaces

- What I have: `PROVA DB2.? RACF2`
- What I want: `PROVA DB RACF`
- What I obtain with my function: `PROVADBRACF`

what can I do? Thank you,
Marina

Comment: Instead of regular expressions, you could use the compress function with modifiers. See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`UPCASE(prxchange(" s/[^A-Z\s\t]*//i",-1,variable));`

`\t` -- all tabs
`\s` -- all spaces

Code:

```
data l;
variable="PROVA DB2.? RACF2";
v2=UPCASE(prxchange(" s/[^\w\s\t]//i",-1,variable));
run;
```

Result:
`PROVA DB RACF`

Answer (score 0):

Add a space to the **character class**.  I put the space after the `Z`, although it could have also gone before the `A`

```
UPCASE(prxchange("s/[^A-Z ]//i",-1,variable));
```

A quick summary of regex in SAS can be found at [Perl Regular Expressions Tip Sheet](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf)

The negated character class specifier `[^]` enumerates the characters to keep (or not-match) during a substitution operation.

```
[^A-Z]
```

means do not match anything that is not between the letters `A` to `Z`, which does not include the space character, so the spaces are getting removed.

The expression you wrote for substitution is *remove any sequence that matches not a letter*

Answer (score 0):

A simple compress function is enough in this scenario as mentioned by @dork horsten

```
data test;
  variable="PROVA DB2.? RACF2";
  v2= compress(variable,'.?');
run;
```